# PHP не выводится false, 0

Tags: php, echo

```
$test = 0,
$test2 = false;
echo $test.' '.$test2;
```

Почему? Так же если создать массив и вывести его он будет отображать как [0] => пустота, не понимаю. Мне нужно хранить в переменных эти значения и в дальнейшем выводить.

Comment: Особенности языка. Boolean не строка, их не вывести как строку. Да и не может быть таких ситуаций, когда Вам необходимо выводить булевы переменные на экран, а если есть, значит что-то делаете не так.

Comment: @Лукас `var_dump($test, $test2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = 0;
$test2 = false;
$test2 = ($test2) ? 'true' : 'false';
echo $test.' '.$test2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что есть ЗНАЧЕНИЕ переменной (например, false), а есть СТРОКОВОЕ ПРЕДСТАВЛЕНИЕ (для false оно будет ""(пустая строка)).

Если хотите выводить больше инфы, можете попробовать так:

```
$test = 0;
$test2 = false;
echo var_export($test, true).' '.var_export($test2, true);
```